# 2D WPF Game, what are my options?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, 2d, game-engine

what would be my options if i would like to create a 2D action game in WPF(for the ease of building UI Layout) without having noticeable performance loss? The game should'nt have heavy physics calculations.

I did create XNA game in the past, and i know about the MonoGame project, but i am still unsure how to use WPF as a host for MonoGame and i didnt find a downloadable example of MonoGame in WPF.

Beside MonoGame, what will be the other options, if any?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at Nick Gravelyn's article which renders XNA inside of a WPF application. I believe MonoGame's API is very similar, if not identical, to XNA, so it shouldn't be a huge problem fixing any porting issues.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/07/25/rendering-with-xna-framework-4-0-inside-of-a-wpf-application.aspx

or

http://www.jfmajor.com/post/38447851593/monogame-in-wpf

I do remember reading somewhere that a team attempting to render WPF controls over XNA/MonoGame (I forget which) did encounter some perf issues.

I think the approach taken by many (from what I've seen) is not to use WPF for rendering a UI and instead build the UI as part of the game/engine. WPF/WinForms can be used to build an editor, but again I believe the rendering of the game/world is embedded within a WPF/WinForms application using a UserControl similar to the articles mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/), both 3D and 2D are supported.

The tutorials have examples on integrating with WPF.